# Hide keyboard only on click, keep it if user is scrolling

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, scrollview

I am trying to hide the keyboard when the user taps on screen. Yet, for example, if there is a layout with a ScrollView (let's say a form with multiple EditTexts), the app must not close the keyboard if the user is **scrolling.** Any idea?

- Main Activity

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            val focusedView = currentFocus
            if (focusedView is EditText) {
                val areaOutsideFocusedView = Rect()
                focusedView.getGlobalVisibleRect(areaOutsideFocusedView)
                if (!areaOutsideFocusedView.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    hideKeyboard()
                    val rootViewGroup = focusedView.rootView as ViewGroup
                    val descendantFocusability = rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability
                    rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS
                    focusedView.clearFocus()
                    rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability = descendantFocusability
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this by adding a variable which stores the last event action.

```
var lastEventAction : Int = -1

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if(lastEventAction != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            val focusedView = currentFocus
            if (focusedView is EditText) {
                val areaOutsideFocusedView = Rect()
                focusedView.getGlobalVisibleRect(areaOutsideFocusedView)
                if (!areaOutsideFocusedView.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    hideKeyboard()
                    val rootViewGroup = focusedView.rootView as ViewGroup
                    val descendantFocusability = rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability
                    rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS
                    focusedView.clearFocus()
                    rootViewGroup.descendantFocusability = descendantFocusability
                }
            }
        }
        lastEventAction = event.action
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
```